# Vue.js remove div from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'have this template in my `vue.js 2.0` app:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="xs:w-full md:w-auto button-main" @click="show = true">
            Open filters
        </button>

        <portal to="port-details">
            <div class="modal" v-if="show">
                <p>jow</p>
            </div>
        </portal>
    </div>
</template>
```

I need to remove the surrounding div because otherwise my markup looks weird. But if I remove that I obviously will get this error:

> Component template should contain exactly one root element

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Based on your example I would just move the `button` under the portal tag and remove the `div`. But in more complex examples you may try to build two components one which will update the `show` and second that will bind to `show`.

Comment: What do you mean by "markup looks weird"? Are you describing the code? or the way it renders in the browser? It would help to see what it looks like and what you're expecting it to look like (as well as any relevant CSS). Can you provide a demo link (e.g., [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue))?

Comment: Vue components must have exactly one root element, there's nothing you can do about that (unless the component is functional).